# How can I test if a JQM form element is Enhanced?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am trying to programatically test if a form element is 'enhanced' from the default markup. I realize I could traverse the DOM and look for a fieldcontains or other JQM specific attribute or tag, but is there a better way?

Since each form element differs in the enhanced markup, i was hoping for a way to test:

```
$('#myformelementid').isEnhanced()
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for a way to access the property through a custom function?  I think you should be able to use [fn.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/):

```
// Before your widget logic
$.fn.extend({
    isEnhanced: function() {
        return this.jqmData('isEnhanced');
    }
});
```

Comment: My original post had the wrong function for adding a data attribute on element creation - it was the factory method for creating a custom element. So yes, that is what I am looking for. Now I just need to find a way to extend the create method to attach the jqmData attribute to all new widgets. I'll look at extend and see what I can find - thanks!